# Is the property of an object set or not?

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there is a way to know if a parameter has been set. For example I have my object User.

```
public class User{
    public int Oid{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Test{ get; set; }
}
```

I create an instance of my object and I set the property Oid and Name but not Test. I would like know this.

```
User u = new User();
u.Oid = 1;
u.Name = "Test";
```

It's possible?

TY

Comment: Is an empty string considered "set" or "not set" ?

Comment: side note: you can set property when declaring `public string Name{ get; set; } = "Test"`; this possibility makes the question being vague (does `u.Name = "Test";` set the property)?

Comment: What if someone does `u.Test = null;` was it "set"? What if someone does `User u = new User(); u.Oid = 0;`? **If** it works for your case, you could try something like `if (u.Name == default)` (or `default(int)` or `default(string)` or whatever type; on older versions). -- If you really really need to know, you might want to take a look at [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification).

Comment: A property is considered set if only the set method is called.
public string Name{ get; set; } = "Test" --> no set

Comment: @PaoloBuzzi - There is no built in way (that I know of) to easily know, if the setter of an auto-property is called (_maybe_ with some weird reflection shenanigans), So you'll probably need to fully implement backing field + getter and setter method yourself. And then you can do something in the setter. -- As I suggested, maybe something similar to `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

For reference types, a property (or field) which is not set will have the value `null`. Because `string` is a reference type, you can check this very easy:

```
if(u.Test == null)
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Property test of variable u is not set!");
 }
```

For other types it is not so easy. `bool` variables will be false by default, and all numeric values like `int` `uint`, `double` etc will be 0. But of course, somebody might have set it fully aware to these values.

You can get the default value of any type via the following:

```
int x = default(int); // will be 0
string y = default(y); // will be null
bool z = default(bool); // will be false;
```

**ADDENDUM:** A completely different approach will be the following:

```
public class User{
    public int Oid{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    private string test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set {test = value; IsTestSet = true; }
    }

    public bool IsTestSet {get; private set;}
}
```

With this code, you can check the property `IsTestSet` to determine whether the setter was called at least once.

Comment: Of course, your method only applies to strings. I would like something valid for all types. I had also thought about the nullable types but I would like to know there was another way.

Comment: @Paolo Buzzi: I added another approach. Maybe this one is better for your needs.

Comment: the second approach is one of the solution I had thought. Another is to create a list of properties with at least a set, to not create several properties

Comment: @PaoloBuzzi: You could use a Dictionary<string,bool> for this. In the setter, you could then use a statement like `IsPropertySet[(nameof(Test)] = true;`.

Comment: @PaoloBuzzi `You can get the default value of any type via the following` - note that on _properties_, exactly what is described there is done _automatically_ by the .Net framework to initialise them. This is internal, though, and does not call the `set` function.

Comment: @Nyerguds I can get the dafault value of any type, but I must be able to set the poprierty to the default value, and keep track of the use of the set method.

Comment: @SomeBody Why do you recommend a dictionary? there would be no value entry to false. Isn't the best choice a list?

Comment: @PaoloBuzzi: Of course you have to initialize your dictionary in the constructor of your class and set all values initially to false. You could use reflection for this. The dictionary has the great advantage that you can easly map your properties to the values.If you have a list, index 0 might be Oid, index 1 might be Name and index 2 might be Test. But this becomes quickly very confusing if you have a lot of properties.

Comment: @SomeBody I have a large number of parameters, but I don't see the problem of managing it with a list. At the start the list is empty then I add the name of parameters with the method set. To find out if that parameter has been set, I only see if it is present in the list. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This's my personal solution.

```
public short oid;
public short Oid
{
     get { return oid; }
     set
     {
         oid = value;
         AddListaSet("Oid");
     }
}
// for all parameter

List<string> ListSet { get; set; } = new List<string>();

private void AddListSet(string name)
{
    if (ListSet.Contains(name) == false)
        ListSet.Add(name);
}
public bool IsSet(string name)
{
    return ListSet.Contains(name) ? true : false;
}
```